# what is the difference between nlogn and logn in the view of how the algorithm grows

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

I have a question reagarding to my lecture datastructures and algortihms.

I have to problem to understand how a algorithm grows. I dont unterstand the difference between the O Notations. And i dont understand the difference between them for example O(lgn)and O(nlgn).

I hope anyone can help me. thank you

Comment: [This](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) shows it pretty well.

Comment: thank you @ChiefTwoPencils :) but can you explain me in your own words why nlgn is worse than lgn? may it's easy .. but i can't understand it very clearly

Comment: Well, it's just math really. If, say, n=8, lgn=3, nlgn=24.

Comment: that you @ChiefTwoPencils =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare time complexities you should be able to make some mathematical proofs. In your example:

for every n>1 we have by multiplying  with logn: nlogn>logn so nlogn is worse than logn. An easy way to understand this is by comparing the graphs of functions as suggested in comments or even try some big inputs to see the asymptotic behavior. For example for n=1000000 :

logn(1000000)=6 and 1000000log(1000000)=6000000 which is greater.

Also notice that you dount count constants in big O notation for example 4n is O(n) , n is O(n)  and also cn+w is O(n) for c,w constants.

Comment: ok does that mean, that for example the heapsort oder quicksort with nlgn is faster that the binary search with logn, right?

Comment: No the opposite , to tell that an algorithm  is faster from  another algorithm , you must show that  first one has LESS complexity than the second . Before we said that logn<nlogn So binary search has complexity logn less than nlogn  so it is faster.

Comment: glad that helped!!